# Why return type is not checked in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types, typechecking

Example from [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-definition-syntax)

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

Right way to call the function with str

```
>>> greeting("John")
'Hello John'
```

If I call it with int:

```
>>> greeting(2)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Call with list

```
>>> greeting(["John"])
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Everything works fine right? `greeting` function always accepts str as a parameter.

But if I try to test function return type, for example, use the same function but change return type to int.

```
def greeting(name: str) -> int:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

Function returns `str` but type is defined as `int`, and no exception is raised:

```
>>> greeting("John")
'Hello John'
```

Another example:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return len(name)

>>> greeting("John")
4
```

Although PEP 484 says that return type is expected to be `str`, it is not actually analogical to argument type check which can be seen in above examples.

> This states that the expected type of the name argument is str.
>   Analogically, the expected return type is str.

Am I missing something or there is no type check for return type?

Comment: Probably that's because your argument to function is still `str` i.e. `greeting(name: str)`

Comment: As the name says, type hints are just _hints_. The python interpreter can completely ignore them when you call a function. Type hints are used so that IDEs can give you information about the type of function arguments and warn you if you call a function with wrong argument types. In your example, the `TypeError` is raised not because of the type hint, but because `'Hello ' + name` does not work if `name` is an `int`.

Comment: @pschill that's true, I misunderstood reason of raising TypeError, thanks

Comment: The other question I duplicate-linked to is newer and has fewer votes, but I really think it's a better formulation of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question might cause a bit confusion for newcomers to python3 type hints. There is no type checking support in python3. This means that python interpreter will not raise an exception if you pass incorrect type in arguments.

[mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) can be used for in case you need this feature.

The actual reason for raising `TypeError` in examples above is unsafe use of `(+)` operator.
If you change function provided in the examples using string formatting

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello {}'.format(name)
```

All of the above cases will work without raising `TypeError`, and no type checking will happen during runtime.

Type Hinting is used by IDEs like PyCharm, [PyCharm Type Hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html), but it is just warnings showed by IDE, not by python interpreter.

Answer (score 7):

The [abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract) of the PEP states:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual
> `__annotations__` attribute, no type checking happens at runtime. Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily. Essentially, such a type checker acts as a very powerful linter. (While it would of course be possible for individual users to employ a similar checker at run time for Design By Contract enforcement or JIT optimization, those tools are not yet as mature.)